# Reading a php file from another php file

Tags: php, file, echo

I currently have a php file that I'm using as a template but I need it to read in data from another php file that I'm using for the page content. I'm doing it this way to save on code and time, however it doesn't appear to be working. I have done a test with shorter amounts of code but it still isn't working. they are both .php files.

Code -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        $temp = 'test-2.php';
        $file = fopen($temp, 'r');
        $cont = fread($file, filesize($temp));
        print $cont;
        fclose($file);
    ?>
</body>
```

test-2.php

```
<?php
echo 'hello world';
?>
```

Comment: It's the difference between reading a file - and - interpreting a file. Andy Holmes' solution should be working for you. If you want to read files in the future there is a shorter way: `echo file_get_contents($temp);` :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use `<?php include('test-2.php'); ?>` surely that'll do what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much i have spent the last 3 days trying to fix this and it now works :)